# apt update stuck at "Generating grub configuration file"

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, 22.04, kubuntu

Running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS for a long time now.. Never any problems, but today when I did an apt upgrade things seemed to get stuck (see further below for entire log):

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
...
...
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.

Progress: [ 96%]
```

What do I do? Since things are stuck I'm scared that grub may be in a bad state... How do I diagnose and fix what's going on?

Thank you!

Full log:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-gtksource-4 input-remapper-daemon input-remapper-gtk libdav1d-dev libgtksourceview-4-0 libgtksourceview-4-common libwmf0.2-7 linux-headers-5.15.0-100 linux-headers-5.15.0-100-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-82
  linux-headers-5.15.0-82-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-83 linux-headers-5.15.0-83-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-84 linux-headers-5.15.0-84-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-86 linux-headers-5.15.0-86-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-87
  linux-headers-5.15.0-87-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-88 linux-headers-5.15.0-88-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-89 linux-headers-5.15.0-89-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-91 linux-headers-5.15.0-91-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-92
  linux-headers-5.15.0-92-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-94 linux-headers-5.15.0-94-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-97 linux-headers-5.15.0-97-generic linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic linux-headers-6.2.0-31-generic
  linux-headers-6.2.0-32-generic linux-headers-6.2.0-33-generic linux-headers-6.2.0-34-generic linux-headers-6.2.0-35-generic linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic linux-headers-6.5.0-15-generic
  linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic linux-headers-6.5.0-18-generic linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-26 linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-31 linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-32 linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-33 linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-34
  linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-35 linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-36 linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-37 linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-15 linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-17 linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-18 linux-image-5.15.0-100-generic
  linux-image-5.15.0-82-generic linux-image-5.15.0-83-generic linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic linux-image-5.15.0-86-generic linux-image-5.15.0-87-generic linux-image-5.15.0-88-generic linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic
  linux-image-5.15.0-91-generic linux-image-5.15.0-92-generic linux-image-5.15.0-94-generic linux-image-5.15.0-97-generic linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic linux-image-6.2.0-31-generic linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic
  linux-image-6.2.0-33-generic linux-image-6.2.0-34-generic linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic linux-image-6.5.0-15-generic linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic
  linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-100-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-82-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-83-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-84-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-86-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-87-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-88-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-89-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-91-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-92-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-94-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-97-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic
  linux-modules-6.2.0-31-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-32-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-33-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-34-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-35-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-36-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-37-generic
  linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic linux-modules-6.5.0-15-generic linux-modules-6.5.0-17-generic linux-modules-6.5.0-18-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-100-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-82-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-83-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-84-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-86-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-87-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-88-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-89-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-91-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-92-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-94-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-97-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-31-generic
  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-32-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-33-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-34-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-35-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-36-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic
  linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-15-generic linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-17-generic linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-18-generic python3-inputremapper python3-pydbus
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  vlc-plugin-qt libvlc5 exo-utils vlc-data gsasl-common libvlccore9 vlc
  imagemagick libavcodec-extra vlc-bin libjs-jquery-ui vlc-l10n libavdevice58
  ffmpeg libopenexr25 python3-scipy libpostproc55 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra
  vlc-plugin-samba libgsasl7 traceroute libmagickwand-6.q16-6
  libavcodec-extra58 vlc-plugin-notify libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16
  libswscale5 libeditorconfig0 xrdp libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libexo-2-0
  vlc-plugin-access-extra vlc-plugin-skins2 libgsl27 vlc-plugin-video-splitter
  libswresample3 imagemagick-6-common vlc-plugin-video-output libavformat58
  libpmix-dev libgslcblas0 libpmix2 libvlc-bin libvlc-dev vlc-plugin-base
  vlc-plugin-visualization libexo-common libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-101 linux-headers-5.15.0-101-generic linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-26 linux-image-5.15.0-101-generic linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-101-generic
  linux-modules-6.5.0-26-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-101-generic linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-26-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  expressvpn libldap-2.5-0 libldap-common linux-generic linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-headers-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-image-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-libc-dev
  python3-update-manager update-manager-core
13 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 248 MB/271 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,306 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-5.15.0-101-generic amd64 5.15.0-101.111 [22.6 MB]                                                                                                         
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-image-5.15.0-101-generic amd64 5.15.0-101.111 [11.5 MB]                                                                                                           
Get:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-101-generic amd64 5.15.0-101.111 [63.9 MB]                                                                                                   
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 5.15.0.101.98 [1,698 B]                                                                                                                             
Get:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 5.15.0.101.98 [2,486 B]                                                                                                                       
Get:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.15.0-101 all 5.15.0-101.111 [12.3 MB]                                                                                                                   
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.15.0-101-generic amd64 5.15.0-101.111 [2,876 kB]                                                                                                        
Get:8 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 5.15.0.101.98 [2,332 B]                                                                                                                     
Get:9 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-6.5.0-26-generic amd64 6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1 [25.6 MB]                                                                                                      
Get:10 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic amd64 6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1 [14.0 MB]                                                                                                       
Get:11 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-26-generic amd64 6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1 [76.8 MB]                                                                                               
Get:12 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-generic-hwe-22.04 amd64 6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13 [1,722 B]                                                                                                           
Get:13 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 amd64 6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13 [2,578 B]                                                                                                     
Get:14 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-26 all 6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1 [13.3 MB]                                                                                                       
Get:15 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic amd64 6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1 [3,448 kB]                                                                                                    
Get:16 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 amd64 6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13 [2,426 B]                                                                                                   
Get:17 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-generic-hwe-20.04 amd64 5.15.0.101.98 [2,354 B]                                                                                                                  
Get:18 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.15.0-101.111 [1,333 kB]                                                                                                                         
Fetched 248 MB in 16s (15.5 MB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
(Reading database ... 1320428 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-python3-update-manager_1%3a22.04.19_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-update-manager (1:22.04.19) over (1:22.04.18) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-update-manager-core_1%3a22.04.19_all.deb ...
Unpacking update-manager-core (1:22.04.19) over (1:22.04.18) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-libldap-2.5-0_2.5.17+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-2.5-0:amd64 (2.5.17+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (2.5.16+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-libldap-common_2.5.17+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-common (2.5.17+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (2.5.16+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.15.0-101-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../04-linux-modules-5.15.0-101-generic_5.15.0-101.111_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.15.0-101-generic (5.15.0-101.111) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-5.15.0-101-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../05-linux-image-5.15.0-101-generic_5.15.0-101.111_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.15.0-101-generic (5.15.0-101.111) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-101-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../06-linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-101-generic_5.15.0-101.111_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-101-generic (5.15.0-101.111) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-linux-generic_5.15.0.101.98_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (5.15.0.101.98) over (5.15.0.100.97) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-linux-image-generic_5.15.0.101.98_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (5.15.0.101.98) over (5.15.0.100.97) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-101.
Preparing to unpack .../09-linux-headers-5.15.0-101_5.15.0-101.111_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-101 (5.15.0-101.111) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-101-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../10-linux-headers-5.15.0-101-generic_5.15.0-101.111_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-101-generic (5.15.0-101.111) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-linux-headers-generic_5.15.0.101.98_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (5.15.0.101.98) over (5.15.0.100.97) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-6.5.0-26-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../12-linux-modules-6.5.0-26-generic_6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../13-linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic_6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-26-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../14-linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-26-generic_6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-linux-generic-hwe-22.04_6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13) over (6.5.0.25.25~22.04.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04_6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13) over (6.5.0.25.25~22.04.12) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-26.
Preparing to unpack .../17-linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-26_6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-26 (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../18-linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic_6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../19-linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04_6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13) over (6.5.0.25.25~22.04.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../20-linux-generic-hwe-20.04_5.15.0.101.98_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic-hwe-20.04 (5.15.0.101.98) over (5.15.0.100.97) ...
Preparing to unpack .../21-linux-libc-dev_5.15.0-101.111_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-101.111) over (5.15.0-100.110) ...
Preparing to unpack .../22-expressvpn_3.66.0.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking expressvpn (3.66.0.2-1) over (3.65.0.5-1) ...
Setting up expressvpn (3.66.0.2-1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/init.d/expressvpn ...
Upgrade in progress...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-101.111) ...
Setting up linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-26 (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
Setting up libldap-common (2.5.17+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libldap-2.5-0:amd64 (2.5.17+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.15.0-101 (5.15.0-101.111) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-26-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
unset ARCH; [ ! -h /usr/bin/cc ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'make' -j16 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=6.5.0-26-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT= modules.................
Signing module:
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/6.5.0-26-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia-uvm.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/6.5.0-26-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/6.5.0-26-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia-peermem.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/6.5.0-26-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia-modeset.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/6.5.0-26-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia-drm.ko
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
cleaning build area...

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-peermem.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-26-generic KERNEL_DIR=/lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/build all...
Signing module:
 - /var/lib/dkms/v4l2loopback/0.12.7/6.5.0-26-generic/x86_64/module/v4l2loopback.ko
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
cleaning build area...

v4l2loopback.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...
   ...done.
Setting up linux-modules-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
Setting up python3-update-manager (1:22.04.19) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13) ...
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.15.0-100-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-100-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.5.0-26-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
Setting up linux-headers-5.15.0-101-generic (5.15.0-101.111) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-101-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
unset ARCH; [ ! -h /usr/bin/cc ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'make' -j16 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=5.15.0-101-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/5.15.0-101-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT= modules..............
Signing module:
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/5.15.0-101-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia-uvm.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/5.15.0-101-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/5.15.0-101-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia-peermem.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/5.15.0-101-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia-modeset.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.147.05/5.15.0-101-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia-drm.ko
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
cleaning build area...

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-101-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-101-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-101-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-101-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-peermem.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-101-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=5.15.0-101-generic KERNEL_DIR=/lib/modules/5.15.0-101-generic/build all...
Signing module:
 - /var/lib/dkms/v4l2loopback/0.12.7/5.15.0-101-generic/x86_64/module/v4l2loopback.ko
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
cleaning build area...

v4l2loopback.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-101-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...
   ...done.
Setting up linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13) ...
Setting up linux-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (5.15.0.101.98) ...
Setting up update-manager-core (1:22.04.19) ...
Setting up linux-generic-hwe-20.04 (5.15.0.101.98) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.15.0-101-generic (5.15.0-101.111) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.5.0-26-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.15.0-101-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-101-generic
Setting up linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-101-generic (5.15.0-101.111) ...
Setting up linux-modules-5.15.0-101-generic (5.15.0-101.111) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (5.15.0.101.98) ...
Setting up linux-generic (5.15.0.101.98) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-26-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-21-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-17-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-14-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-101-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-100-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-100-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-97-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-97-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-94-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-94-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-92-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-92-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-89-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-89-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-88-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-88-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-87-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-87-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-86-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-86-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-84-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-84-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-83-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-83-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-82-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-82-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.

Progress: [ 96%] [#############################################################################################################################################################################################################.........]
```

Comment: You need to do the recommended: Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. Do you have other partitions like NTFS that may be locked with fast startup or bitlocker? Or needs chkdsk? Or an ext4 partition that needs fsck? Os-prober may then hang up. I houseclean old kernels & turn off os-prober. And add only the other systems I want to boot into 40_custom. Do you have good backups? And a live installer to repair/boot if grub does not work?